# Qty for item status to become out of stock negative value malfunction

Tags: inventory, backorder

When on the `Inventory` tab whilst editing a product there is the option to set `Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock`.

I've enabled `Backorders` on the product & would like to set the out of stock value to a negative number, thus only accepting a limited amount of backorders.

However, Magento doesn't seem to set the product to out of stock once that negative stock level is reached. Is this functionality not natively supported by Magento?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I experienced and remember, the activation of back-orders completely ignores the Become Out of Stock value here.
Or at least triggers the item to be a backorder (not sure about this)

Answer (score 0):

No, the "Allow Backorders" functionality cannot be set up that way without custom code. By default, it simply ignores the In/Out of stock value, except to mark the product as "Backordered" on the order when the quantity is in the negative.